# Is there an OOP language with optional type hinting?

Tags: oop, type-hinting

Basically I'm looking for something similar to PHP, OOP, and with type hinting for all data types (in PHP you can't type-hint integers, strings, floats, nor bools, and they are not classes).

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you define "type-hinting" further?. Python does OOP and provides some form of  optional type-checking via asserts and function decorators, but it does not check types at compile time, only at usage.

Comment: @macke Yes I think type-hinting is a type-check on runtime (also useful to give hints to the IDE), like what you described.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/) ?

It has classical OOP and optional typing.